Help identifying a disturbing thriller I saw on netflix 2-4 years ago
I only remember parts of the movie, but it kind of follows the story of this teen boy with long hair i think from a broken home. The movie starts with the teen and i think his younger brothers being sexually assaulted by their moms boyfriend I believe, while shes gone. He takes photographs of them then sits down to read the newspaper I think, while still naked. The mom comes home and discovers this and aggressively reacts to the man.
The rest of the movie shows the teen getting caught up in some bad activity influenced by a family friend I believe. He sort of recruits the teen to following and participating in them abducting and torturing people. One scene I remember involves a bloody half awake man being tortured in a bathtub while a few other people involved look. I think they were ripping out fingernails or something. 
Anyways, I think the movie ends with them all being caught by the police but I could be wrong. I think it might also be based on a true story. Its full colour (has a pretty cold almost slightly blue filter tho), and relatively new I believe. Probably from the 2000's. The movie's in English. I believe it's an indie movie.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Thanks for the feedback, I adjusted the question a bit to add what little more detail I can remember. The big problem here is that I just don't remember that much unfortunately lol, all I know is that it was disturbing in an incredible way and parts of it has stuck with me for a long time, I really hope to see it again someday.

@D_ev - what country are you based in? As Netflix shows different content depending on the region.

I'm from Canada, so Canadian netflix, which does have a smaller selection than the US counterpart I believe

It may be tedious but going through your previous viewing activity (netflix.com/viewingactivity) might jog your memory if you go back to the time frame you're thinking of.

I'm not sure if it would go back that far and still have films that they no longer have up on netflix, but i suppose its worth a shot. I'll post here if i manage to find anything, thanks

OMG wow I can't believe I didn't just try going through my history forever ago. The movie is called 'The Snowtown Murders', its a 2011 movie. Apparently I saw it back in 2013. Thanks so much @BlueGI for pointing out such an obvious solution lol, and thanks everyone who responded.
I highly recommend it if you're into this kinda thing, here's the trailer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXgxhH01ea0

The Snowtown Murders. Single mother finds out the guy across the street has been molesting her boys and she runs him out. Then she gets a boyfriend who decides to avenge the wrongs the boys suffered by torturing and killing all the bad people around. 
Read below for the following passage of The SnowTown Murders(2011):

Sixteen-year-old Jamie lives with his mother, Elizabeth, and two younger brothers, Alex and Nicholas, in a housing trust home in Adelaide's northern suburbs. Their home is but one of many sun-starved houses crammed together to cater for a disenfranchised society. Jamie longs for an escape from the violence and hopelessness that surrounds him and his salvation arrives in the form of John, a charismatic man who unexpectedly comes to his aid. As John spends more and more time with Jamie's family, Elizabeth and her boys begin to experience a stability and sense of family that they have never known. John moves from the role of Jamie's protector to that of a mentor, indoctrinating Jamie into his world, a world brimming with bigotry, righteousness and malice. Like a son mimicking his father, Jamie soon begins to take on some of John's traits and beliefs as he spends more and more time with him and his select group of friends. The protection and guidance that John presents to Jamie is initially welcomed however as events occur around him, including the disappearance of several people, Jamie begins to harbour deep suspicions about John and his motivations. When the truth is finally revealed to Jamie his hopes of happiness are threatened by both his loyalty for, and fear of, his father-figure John Bunting, Australia's most notorious serial killer. 

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1680114/

Are you able to give a plot description from the site link you have just put up as this helps?

Also known as "Snowtown".
